# How to add click event to jstree's(jQuery plugin) asynchronous list?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jstree

I want to add click event to [jstree](http://www.jstree.com/)'s asynchronous list items.

The ideal result is: when i click the items in the jstree, the content of the item will be transfered to a sql query as a parameter, and then, the query is executed and display a result set in the same page or in another page.

While I don't know how to implement it. I found the following code in jquery.tree.js. And I think I should modify the event. But i don't know how. Can you see the code and give me some suggestions or guidance?

```
$("#" + this.container.attr("id") + " li a")
 .live("click.jstree", function (event) { // WHEN CLICK IS ON THE TEXT OR ICON
  if(event.which && event.which == 3) return true;
  if(_this.locked) {
   event.preventDefault(); 
   event.target.blur();
   return _this.error("LOCKED");
  }
  _this.select_branch.apply(_this, [event.target, event.ctrlKey || _this.settings.rules.multiple == "on"]);
  if(_this.inp) { _this.inp.blur(); }
   event.preventDefault();
   event.target.blur();
   return false;
  })
```

The page code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(function () { 
        $("#async_json_1").tree({
            data : { 
                type : "json",
                opts : {
                    url : "twodimen.php"
                }
            },
            callback:{
                onselect: function(node,tree){

                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the callback method [onselect](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/#callback.onselect) which usually takes place when the node is clicked (even though you can also select it by script)

if your nodes (the li) have an id of the form "node_1234", then:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
 $(function () { 
  $("#async_json_1").tree({
   data : { 
    type : "json",
    opts : {
     url : "twodimen.php"
    }
   },
   callback: {
      onselect: function(node, tree) {
         var id = $(node).attr("id").split("_")[1]; // that is 1234
         $.ajax({
            url: "your/url",
            data: "id="+id,
            success: function(data){
               alert("Great");
            }
         });
      }
   }
  });
 });
</script>
```

---

I just realized, that there is also an even simpler way of doing what you need:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
 $(function () { 
  $("#async_json_1").tree({
   data : { 
    type : "json",
    opts : {
     url : "twodimen.php"
    }
   }
  });
  $(".tree a").live("click", function(e) {
     // your code here
  }) 
 });
</script>
```

Comment: @Harpax, thanks. I need to do some DOM manipulation in the onselect section?

Comment: if I understood your question correct, then no .. you can get the nodes id (the id from the li) simply with $(node).attr("id") and use that for the ajax call to do your db-query

Answer (score 0):

```
.delegate("a","click", function(e) {
         console.log($(this).parent().attr("id").split("_")[1]); //get ID of clicked node
  })
```